# How to make both parent and child view scrollable

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-scroll

I have a view which has a `Spinner` and a `Linearlayout` int it. The `Linearlayout` serves as a parent to a child layout. The child layout is inflated programmatically. The child view has a `CardView` with `TextView` and a listview in the `CardView`.

My problem is I want to make the whole view (view with `Spinner` and `LinearLayout`) scrollable and and childview too. But whenever I try to scroll the listview inside that `CardView`, the whole view scrolls. When the user tries to scroll ListView, the view inside my child layout should only scroll.

This is my parent layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner
        android:id="@+id/shelfShareSelectionSpiiner"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_180sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="Select Category" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/shelfShareLinearlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp" />


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is my child view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/shelfShareMasterLL"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/frontalRodShareCardView"

        android:layout_width="@dimen/_292sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_250sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_4sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/_3sdp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/shelfShareMasterRL"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/shelfShareHeadingTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:text="Frontal Rod Share"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp" />


            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/shelfShareProductListView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </ListView>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using NestedScrollview instead of ScrollView ?

Comment: Yes, I have. I replaced nested scrollview with scrollview in my parent layout but it didn't worked.